# How to make multi type voltage input? 24AC/DC to 24DC?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply

Task: Input voltage: 24V AC or DC (Client disides what to input into divice) output voltage 24V dc output current 1.25A.

Buck-boost converter is a simple and expensive solution. I need some how to dicide to regulate voltage when AC is an input and pass thrue when input is DC. Please help, sorry for English!

Comment: A switch would work equally as well. Like on PSU's where there is a 110/240V slider. Or just have different connectors for AC/DC

Comment: Switch in not an option. To much thinking on Client side. The solution have to be plug AC or DC 24V and go no switches. Thats why this question is so hard.

Comment: Different plug then? that's fairly standard for incompatible voltages

Comment: Don't have that luxury PCB is full (Where is connectors) and dimensions can't be altered. Besides Clients are too dumb to connect it correctly.

Comment: tell me about it

Comment: What do you think about undervoltage overvoltage detection, when over regulage when under pass. Is this eavin posable? I have one OpAMP free in schematic.

Comment: 24VAC to 24VDC is easy - rectifier and regulator. 24VDC on the same input will be problematic as the rectifer(s) will drop at least 0.6V and the regulator will not have sufficient headroom to pass the DC through. A buck-boost seems like the only reasonable solution. Hopefully the "dumb" client doesn't mind a high BOM cost.

Comment: i realise that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the schematic showing the 24VAC/24VDC switching scheme.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer, but voltage drop on bridge is still there, so when 24Vdc is applied the output still gonna be 22,6V that is not allowed.

Comment: You are most welcome. The scheme has been modified to address the voltage drop issue.

Comment: Thank you, Kubilius.